# Pushing UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

Is there any way to push a view controller With customizing the display on screen ? , like presenting a view controller , `modalPresentationStyle = .custom`. *! When pushing a view controller with custom animation, the pushed view controller disappears.*

Answer (score 0):

You can push by assigning your desired animation at the time of transition:

```
let yourVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YOURVIEWCONTROLLER") as! YOURVIEWCONTROLLER
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, animations: {() -> Void in
    UIView.setAnimationCurve(.easeInOut)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(yourVC, animated: true)
    UIView.setAnimationTransition(.flipFromRight, for: (self.navigationController?.view)!, cache: false)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do custom animations for pushing view controllers.

You can implement your own UINavigationControllerDelegate where you can trigger your own transition animation. There are a lot of sites which explain how to do it. You can check [here](https://theswiftdev.com/ios-custom-transition-tutorial-in-swift/) , [here](https://medium.com/@samstone/create-custom-uinavigationcontroller-transitions-in-ios-1acd6a0b6d25) and there a lot of examples for UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning. Just look for some nice tutorials, how to be implemented.

Comment: I know how to make a transition animation , the problem  of pushing a view controller is if I want to display it on half of the screen for example , the fromViewController will disappear, not like presenting a viewController .

Comment: it depends on what you need you can copy the view as an image from fromView and keep showing it. But if you need interaction for it, then you should not use a push mechanism.

Comment: Good idea, thank you . I will present it instead of push it .